# looking for Parse alternative server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm a hobby developer that use Parse.com as my database and website host, as Facebook is going to shutdown Parse.com, I'm now looking for alternative Parse server.

I use Parse's Cloud Code Hosting to build Dynamic Web App, and Parse itself to store data collected from the website I've build, with custom Cloud Code to help getting and managing data. I've build a Windows Phone app for myself to manage the data I've collected too.

Is there any alternative server that has my requirement?

> Dynamic Website
>
> Database host
>
> Custom Cloud Code (with BeforeSave and AfterSave trigger)
>
> with Windows Phone SDK (or REST API if doesn't have)

Very thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Try out Hasura.

Hasura (http://www.hasura.io): Hasura is a neat PaaS + BaaS solution.  It is now competing with Firebase, Kinvey, Heroku et al.  There is a full comparison page here: Compare | Hasura (https://compare.beta.hasura.io) . The difference majorly lies in infra ownership as well as no tech lock-in due to open-source components(like docker, kubernetes,postgres) building the major chunk of the platform. Check it out. There is also an option to explore (https://explore.beta.hasura.io/) Hasura by building your own blog web app and a todo app in under 15 mins.

Hasura should fit in perfectly for your needs.

DISCLAIMER : Hasura Engineer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [parse open source server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) it has cloud code and you can use a custom database with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Simbla website application development](http://www.simbla.com/web_applications). It doesn't support all of your requirments but it has great UI builder with a backend parse database.